# Replace text box from auto complete items

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to implement auto complete on a input text element. The code uses a list of countries to auto complete when the use starts typing a letter. How do I replace the value in the text box with the country the user chooses to click from the countries being shown. Codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/zYxvbQq?editors=1010). Thank you.

```
// Country list
const countryList = [
  "Afghanistan",
  "Albania",
  "Algeria",
  "Andorra",
  "Angola",
  "Anguilla",
  "Antarctica",
  "Antigua-and-Barbuda",
  "Argentina",
  "Armenia",
  "Aruba",
  "Australia",
  "Autria",
  "Azerbaïjan"
];

document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  suggestions.innerHTML = "";
  countryList.forEach(country => {
    if (country.startsWith(e.target.value)) {
      suggestions.innerHTML += country + "<br>";
    };
  });

});
```

Comment: Use a data list, it does exactly this for you and it's native html - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many autocomplete libs available you can just google it.

But i have modified you code, you can check it, it will not robust but you can improve it. you can check out [codepen](https://codepen.io/saurabhkhoshya/pen/povjBRJ?editors=1010).

```js
// Country list
const countryList = [
  "Afghanistan",
  "Albania",
  "Algeria",
  "Andorra",
  "Angola",
  "Anguilla",
  "Antarctica",
  "Antigua-and-Barbuda",
  "Argentina",
  "Armenia",
  "Aruba",
  "Australia",
  "Autria",
  "Azerbaïjan"
];

document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");
  suggestions.innerHTML = "";
  let suggestionTemplage = '<ul>';
  countryList.forEach(country => {
    if (country.startsWith(e.target.value)) {
      suggestionTemplage += `<li data-country="${country}"class="country">${country}</li>`;
 // create a li to set countries name and setclass name country to each li
    };
  });
    suggestionTemplage += '</ul>';
// set suggestions innerHTML to created template of li 
    suggestions.innerHTML = suggestionTemplage;
  
   let elmList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.country'));
// bind click event to each country class which is set in li
    elmList.map((elm) =>{
        elm.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // on click get the country name and set to input element
          document.getElementById("country").value = this.getAttribute('data-country');
          suggestions.innerHTML = "";
        });
    });
});
```

```html
A   <label for="country">Enter a country name</label>:
 <input type="text" id="country">
 <div id="suggestions"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of libs but wanted to do this in vanilla js.